# Flutter : didUpdateWidget not giving old value of oldWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I've horizontal list, in which i need to update value for each row. As, it will call didUpdateWidget every time once it's initialized once, we should get old widgets value to match. Issue is i'm not getting oldWidget's value, every time it's providing updated value.

Here, i've attached image for reference.
[image]

It's dynamic list, where if one item is selected it will show same as first item with animation and other should show with down value.
Listview Snippet :

```html
   controller.categories.isNotEmpty
                        ? SizedBox(
                            height: 110.h,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount: controller.categories.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return SpecialMealTile(
                                  index: index,
                                  categories: controller.categories[index],
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        : const SizedBox.shrink(),
```

Tile Snippet:

```html
class SpecialMealTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final Categories categories;

  SpecialMealTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.index,
    required this.categories,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SpecialMealTile> createState() => _SpecialMealTileState();
}

class _SpecialMealTileState extends State<SpecialMealTile>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation _colorTween;
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _animation;
  bool upDown = true;
  final InFlightMealController _inFlightMealController = Get.find();
  late Categories _oldCategory;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: const Interval(0.0, 1.0, curve: Curves.decelerate),
    );
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    );
    _colorTween = ColorTween(begin: ThemeColor.white, end: ThemeColor.darkBlue)
        .animate(_animationController);
    // _up(_inFlightMealController.categories[widget.index]!.isSelected);
    _oldCategory = widget.categories;

    log("--Come--Category--->>>>>> ${widget.categories.isSelected.toString()}");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant SpecialMealTile oldWidget) {
    // print('in did update NEW dependencies' +
    //     widget.categories.isSelected.toString());
    // print(
    //     'in did update OLD dependencies' + _oldCategory.isSelected.toString());

    // if (oldWidget.categories.isSelected != widget.categories.isSelected) {

    _up(_inFlightMealController.categories[widget.index].isSelected);

    log("--Old--Category--->>>>>> ${_oldCategory.isSelected}");
    // }
    // print(inFlightMealController.categories[widget.index]!.isSelected);
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        _onTap();
      },
      child: _childWidget(),
    );
  }

  void _onTap() {
    _inFlightMealController.showNourishSpecial.value =
        !_inFlightMealController.showNourishSpecial.value;
    _inFlightMealController.showHalalFood.value =
        !_inFlightMealController.showHalalFood.value;

    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
      setState(() {
        _inFlightMealController.showNourishSpecial.value =
            !_inFlightMealController.showNourishSpecial.value;
      });
    });

    if (_animationController.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
      _animationController.reverse();
    } else {
      _animationController.forward();
    }
    _inFlightMealController.selectedMeal.value = _inFlightMealController
        .inFlightModel.value.categories![widget.index].categoryInfo!.name!;
    _inFlightMealController.selectedMealIndex.value = widget.index;

    for (int i = 0; i < _inFlightMealController.categories.length; i++) {
      if (i == widget.index) {
        if (_inFlightMealController.categories[i].isSelected) {
          _inFlightMealController.categories[i].isSelected = false;
        } else {
          _inFlightMealController.categories[i].isSelected = true;
        }
      } else {
        _inFlightMealController.categories[i].isSelected = false;
      }
    }
    // _inFlightMealController.categories.refresh();
  }

  Widget _childWidget() {
    return Container(
      width: 108.w,
      margin: ltrb(right: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: HexColor(_inFlightMealController
            .categories[widget.index].categoryInfo!.color!),
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(25),
        ),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animation,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
              return Positioned(
                bottom: 0.0,
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 25.w,
                        height: 3.h,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: HexColor.darken(HexColor(
                              _inFlightMealController.categories[widget.index]
                                  .categoryInfo!.color!)),
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(2),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      HeightSizedBox(8),
                      Container(
                        width: 108.w,
                        height: 90.h * _animation.value == 0
                            ? 20.h
                            : 90.h * _animation.value,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: HexColor.darken(HexColor(
                              _inFlightMealController.categories[widget.index]
                                  .categoryInfo!.color!)),
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Align(
            child: AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _colorTween,
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) => Text(
                _inFlightMealController
                        .categories[widget.index].categoryInfo!.name ??
                    "",
                style: AppFont.SubTitle1_Medium(
                    color: _colorTween.value, size: 12.sp),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _up(bool upDown) {
    if (upDown) {
      upDown = false;
      _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
    } else {
      upDown = true;
      _controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
    }
    /* setState(() {

    });*/
  }
}
```

Comment: Issue is when one item is showing as up and other should show as down with animation. So i need to compare value of each state and i'm not getting old state in didUpdateWidget.